# webapi authentication and authorization wsfed and oauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, restful-authentication, adfs2.0

We have an existing MVC angular application enabled with ADFS WS-Fed authentication. The application has many API's hosted as a part of the solution which is internally accessed by views. Now, We have a requirement for the API to be published to other developers.

I am thinking of enabling OAuth/OpenId for the endpoints and enable other developers to access. I need your inputs regarding my approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in ADFS 2.0 for OpenID Connect and OAuth.

The only API option you have is via WCF.